# Assign action name dynamically in ASP.Net Mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using attribute routing. I assigned a route value to an action ex: contactimage. Sometimes I am getting request from client like `'.../contact image'`, `'.../co ntactimage'` etc. I want to replace the space in the URL and assign action to it. How can I do it?

**Edit 1:** I extended `ControllerFactory`- Create Controller method. I made changes to route values in that method and calling `base.CreateController`. Still system is throwing error.

```
public override IController CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)         
{
    string controllername = requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
    if (controllername.Replace(" ","").ToLower()== "campaignimage")
    {
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "Campaign";
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "CampaignTrackerImage";
        controllerName = controllerName.Replace(" ","");
    }
    return base.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
}
```

Comment: Just no, the urls should not be coming to you with spaces in, that is not a proper URL. Therefore you should be kicking back an error saying route not found.

Comment: This really isn't a problem **you** should be concerned with. MVC will handle this properly...

Comment: Yes, my application is throwing url not found exception. But I am suppose to handle (only) this scenario..

Comment: You would just enable custom errors in your web.config, provide the error page and the rest should be handled by MVC. You should not be trying to validate the URLs that are being passed to your webserver, you'll open yourself up to denial of service attacks, possible intrusion vectors. This is the problem of the caller, they should handle that scenario gracefully not the server.

Comment: Is this for one controller or all controllers?  If it's just for one, say, `spacecadetcontroller` then you can add a custom route that causes anything `spacecadet/{actionname}` to go a specific `Action` method in `spacecadetcontroller` which then processes the `actionname` and redirects to the "real" action desired.

Comment: I tried your solution now.. but not working. :(